# Memory leak when using MBProgressHUD

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, memory-leaks, mbprogresshud

I am using the `MBProgressHUB` as the loading indicter. I noticed via Instruments, There's considerable memory leak when using `MBProgressHUB` **(** Around 3MB each time its initiate. And issue is, memory DOES NOT clear when the view unload **)**.

**Project is ARC enabled**

This is how I am initiate `MBProgressHUB` in `ViewDidLoad` (HUD is retained property too)

```
HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:[(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]     delegate] window]];
[[(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] addSubview:HUD];
HUD.delegate = self;
```

Also in the `ViewDidUnload` I am setting `HUD = nil;`

Any ideas???

Comment: Instruments also shows you where the allocations are... make the most minimal example program you can that still shows the leak and you'll have less noise to search through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I manage to solve the issue by Initializing MBProgressHUB only a single time in the AppDelegate. And use only a reference to that in other places

Answer (score 4):

You are adding your hud to the window as subview. Window holds it in subviews all the time your app is running.

You should call [HUD removeFromSuperview] method when you don't need it or set property HUD.removeFromSuperViewOnHide to YES - so it will remove itself on hiding and deallocate the memory if you are not retaining it elsewhere.

If you added it to the controller's view - it would be deallocated in the end of controller's lifecycle with its view.

Comment: HUD.removeFromSuperViewOnHide = YES is exactly what I was missing! Thanks SerJ_G!

Answer (score 0):

Im doing this with a non-ARC project.

I found a solution just changing the `- (id)initWithView:(UIView *)view {` method. It returns `me` and i changed it to return `[me autorelease]`

Regards